# How to check variable is 'null' || 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code. can you please check it

Java-script code :

```
var fname = $("div#names div#fname").attr('class');
if(fname == 'undefined'){
  //code
};
```

Html Code

```
<div id="names">
  <div id="fname"><input type=""/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `if( !fname)` - done.

Comment: `if(fname == 'undefined')`

Comment: Just use `if (fname != null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check if the variable has a value or not

var fname = $("div#names div#fname").attr('class');

```
if( fname ) {
  // it's defined
}
```

evaluate to true if value is not:

- undefined
- null
- empty string ("")
- NaN
- false
- 0

if you do not know whether a variable exists (that means, if it was declared) you should check with the typeof operator.

```
if( typeof fname !== 'undefined' ) {
    // it's defined
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `typeof`

```js
var fname = $("div#names div#fname").attr('class');
if (typeof fname == 'undefined') {
  console.log("Here");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="names">
  <div id="fname"><input type="" /></div>
</div>
```